# Invalid parameter error for fopen method in C

Tags: c, path, char, fopen

I have searched here for 15-20 similar questions but none of them could solve my problem I still get same errors.

Here I want to read .txt files located in Text_Files folder.(There are three .txt files;doc1.txt,doc2.txt,doc3.txt)

I get either 'No such file or directory' or 'Invalid argument' error. I know that there is something wrong with path and/or the way I put that in fopen method.

```
int main()
{
   
DIR *dir;
FILE* entry_file;
struct dirent *in_file;
char toOpenFiles[1000];
dir = opendir("E:\\C Projects\\Term_Project_2\\Cprojects\\Text_Files");
 while ((in_file = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
   {
    //this part is to be able get file name(It works correctly)
      if (!strcmp(in_file->d_name, "."))
            continue;
      if (!strcmp(in_file->d_name, ".."))
            continue;
//For path I also tried E:\\C Projects\\Term_Project_2\\Cprojects\\ but same error occurs 
      strcpy(toOpenFiles, "\\E:\\C Projects\\Term_Project_2\\Cprojects\\");
    // in_file->d_name returns doc1.txt
      strcat(toOpenFiles, in_file->d_name);
          full_path[0]='\0';
         strcat(full_path,toOpenFiles);
        
        //Here entry_file 's value is 0x0 for some reason
         entry_file = fopen(full_path, "r");
            if (!entry_file)
            {
            //this prints 'No such file or directory' if I put full_path as a parameter in fopen or 'Invalid argument' if I put toOpenFiles
               printf("Error : errno='%s'.\n",strerror(errno));
               
            }
            else
            {
               printf("It's working!");
            }
              closedir(dir);
   
   return 0;
}
```

**Edit**
Is is solved when I change path with this:

```
strcpy(toOpenFiles, "E:\\C Projects\\Term_Project_2\\Cprojects\\Text_Files\\");
```

Comment: It might help if you printed `full_patch` before you call `fopen`. Otherwise you can not really know if you get valid filenames at all.

Comment: Do you intentionally use 2 different path names for reading directory and opening the files? Or should both contain `\\Text_Files` ?

Comment: I see now,both of them should contaion \\Text_Files. What a mistake. Thank you. @Gerhardh.My eyes missed that. I wouldn't see that without your comment. thank u. I think it will work after I change that.

Comment: Then you have identical files in both folders? Otherwise I don't think it can work.

Comment: Also the leading `\\E...` looks a bit strange.

Comment: Please edit the question and include all relevant parameter declarations. `full_path` in particular.

Comment: Use `perror("fopen")` to indicate errors. Also, use `malloc` and `realloc` to concatenate strings, see [the function at the bottom of this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Concatenating-Strings.html).